# How to make sure element has enough gap it can expand to?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

```css
.container{
border: 1px solid #bee3f7;
background: #ebf8ff;
padding: 10px;
display: flex;
max-width: fit-content;
}

.expandable{
padding-bottom: 30px;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
padding: 5px;
}

.fixed{
background: #a6a6a6;
width: 10vw;
height: 13vw;
}

.grow{
height: 0;
transition: height 0.5s linear;
}

.expandable:hover .grow{
height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='expandable'>
<div class='fixed'></div>
<div class='grow'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

In given example I have element expanding together with child, but I want blue element to have `height = height of child + 30px`, so that child element can expand there without pushing container. I'm using React and Styled-Components, so I've tried:

```
<StickyContainer key={index} $height={childEl.offsetHeight}>
          {childEl}
</StickyContainer>

export const StickyContainer = styled.div`
  height: ${(props) => props.$height + 30}px;
`;
```

I got `height: NaNpx;`. I understand that most likely it's because it needs to render it before to be able to get width. Problem is that I need container to be proper height at render.

Comment: height: ${({height}) => height + 30}px; use this as this `$` is not allowed in styled component

Comment: Ridwan Ajibola, it's called transient props and they are allowed. https://styled-components.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) function of CSS.

Comment: Would be a better answer if you expanded and provided an example.

Comment: Doesn't work, even if I use plain code `height: ${(props) => props.$height}px;` it results in `height: px;`

Comment: Use paddingY: 30px;